# Querying pg_buffercache: relation "pg_buffercache" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have PostgreSQL 9.4.7 installed in LXC container on Ubuntu 14.04. For monitoring purposes, i try to execute this from my host machine:
`psql -qAtX -h *** -p *** -U postgres -c "select count(*) from pg_buffercache where isdirty"`, so I am expecting to get a pure decimal value for parsing. However, I get `relation "pg_buffercache" does not exist` error. I have already added pg_buffercache extension (`CREATE EXTENSION pg_buffercache;`), restarted server afterwards and checked if it is present:

```
postgres=# \dx
pg_buffercache | 1.0    | public     | examine the shared buffer cache
```

The strangest thing is, if i execute this query directly in postgresql shell, it works just fine:

```
postgres=# select count(*) from pg_buffercache where isdirty;
count
-------
 113
```

What can cause this? Other queries not using pg_buffercache work perfectly.

Comment: Perhaps your `psql -qAtX` command is not actually connecting to the "postgres" database (or other database where you have `pg_buffercache` insatlled). One way this might happen is if you had env. variable PGDATABASE defined. Can you try adding a database (e.g. `-d postgres`) to your psql command?

Comment: You are right. I was obviously missing the database name. Should put more research into this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to first connect to the database that you need to check the stats from, and in that do the create extension, after which the query should work ;)